# typescript export object error declaration or statement expected

Tags: node.js, typescript

Can someone please explain why this works in typescript while exporting an object:

```
export const config={
port:4000
};
```

This also works:

```
const config = { port:4000 };
export { config };
```

But this gives an error

```
const config={
  port:4000
};
export config;
```

Error : declaration or statement expected.

Comment: im just curious to understand how typescript 'export' differs from node.js 'exports'

Comment: typescript `export` is about the same as javascript [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) which is a newer, better language feature, designed to replace node `exports` but [somewhat incompatible with it](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`export` expects a type object or curly braces. The second version is a syntax error.

If you want to export just a config objects then do

```
export const config = { port:4000 };
```

From the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html):

This can also be written as `export {config}`;

Comment: but isint config an object here? Im sorry im just new with this

Comment: config is an object but your export statement was syntactically incorrect. You need curly braces to export. Also you can export directly by putting export before declaration like mentioned above. @noob7

Comment: as a followup, 
    export default const x = ()=>console.log("abs"); 
also doesnt work but, 
    const x =  ()=>console.log("abs"); 
    export default x; 
works